# When were full-body cyborgs first prototyped, and mass produced?

Tags: lore, shadowrun

As I know at least in the late 60s full body cyborgs exist (thus a cyborg with just a metasapient brain). I'm wondering though when the first ones existed (prototypes and also mass produced). Is there any info on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Around 2065 and 2070

Aparently, their development started around 2065. From 4ed Augmentation (page 148):

> **Cyborgs**
>
> Posted By: The Smiling Bandit
>
> Ever since MCT began internally deploying their anthropomorphic **Otomo drones back in ’65**, folks have commented that things didn’t seem quite right about them.
>
> (...)
>
> **OTOMO Product Announcement**
>
> **Limited Distribution: Full Mitsuhama Subsidiaries Only**
>
> **Clearance: Secure Sensitive Information (SSI) Only**
>
> **Draft v.2.1**
>
> Since the dawn of optional cybernetic implantation, some have pushed their bodies to the limits. As technology advanced, so did those limits. With the advent of cyborg technology, the bar has been raised to a whole new level. Through our exclusive cerebral containment unit (CCU), *a metahuman brain can be conveniently implanted in an entirely cybernetic body*.

The exact date when mass production started is unclear, but by 2070, you could buy your own cyborg. (page 151):

> The preceding fiction introduces Shadowrun players to three different technological breakthroughs that showcase and exploit the cutting edge of augmentation technologies in **2070: biodrones, cyborgs, and cyberzombies**.
>
> (...)
>
> A cyborg requires access to delta-grade implants. This essential modification raises the entry price of a CCU to **250,000¥**.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I *think* there might have been prototypes earlier. Cyberzombies featured in fiction from 2nd Ed days, which were set some time in the 2050s.

Comment: @Adeptus: what's the relation between cyberzombies and fullbody cyborgs? Unless I'm mistaken they are fundamentally different things, though the CCU may have been invented to circumvent the issue of cyberzombies.

Comment: It's been a while since I read the books, but from memory, cyber zombies are basically failed/insane prototypes of full-bodied cyborgs

Comment: I'm not close to the cyborg idea.  but cyberzombies start human and progressively have parts replaced. losing essence all the time.. but through magical means are kept alive.  My guess is that the Cyborgs aren't 'alive' in the same sense.

Comment: Cyberzombies are metahumans who have sub-zero essence. Fullbody "cyborgs" aren't really cyborgs at all by the traditional definition - they're a brain-in-a-jar operating a human-shaped drone. There's very little "org"anism to go with the "cyb"ernetics.